# Cannot get JSON data to display on Leaflet map

Tags: json, leaflet, geojson

I've been struggling with getting leaflet markers to display on a map by pulling in data from a JSON file.  I think I'm missing something very fundamental, since I can even copy working example files from Plunker and load them to my hosts web server.  It just display's the base map but no markers from the JSON file.

Search "**displaying .json files in leaflet**" in Stack Overflow and check Plunker link under the one answer to see the example I've been trying to make work on my hosts web server.

I'm placing all four files in the same folder on the web server.  Works fine when I run it on Plunker, but not on my hosts web server.  Host is GoDaddy :(.  I don't get any error messages, just an empty base map layer.

Is there some setting that may be blocking this?  Totally stumped.  Note, that I can get it to work  fine if I hard code my marker data into the web page, but for the project I'm working on there will be way to many data points, so need to pull this from an external file.  Here is "live" test example where I just hard code data into web page:  http://bwcawild.com/PMA-Pitfall-Lake/Test-Lake/Test2-Lake.html

Anyone got any ideas on this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve]

Comment: probably a cors restriction. the link you posted is pointless, need to see broken one